# Can we call a function through map, passing function name in value of Hashmap function

Tags: java, arrays, enums, hashmap

I have facing one issue, I have to find the position of a robot in a grid, it can move in forward direction and can change its facing towards north, south, east and west and have been provided with a given command sequence. So, what will be the final position of the robot.
Use of any type of condition branching (e.g. if/else,switch/case) is prohibited.

Example-
Grid-(100*500)
Robot's initial Position-(5,3)
Possible commands-
N-North,
E-East,
W-West,
S-South,
M-Move forward
Sample Input-{N,S,M.M,E,W,E,S,M,S,M}

My Algo-
I am thinking that I can use a map where my keys would be commands and values would be function executed on that particular command.
But I am not getting how to call a function through HashMap value.
Also we have to take in consider the end cases when the grid would not have any possible movements left any more.

I tried this code as per suggestion, but not getting how to give dynamic commands using Enum

```
public class RobotMovesInGrid {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String command=input.next();
    int commLength = command.length();

    static enum Command {
        N{@Override public void execute(String g, String r){ System.out.println("do the N move here"); }},
        E{@Override public void execute(String g, String r){ System.out.println("do the E move here"); }},
        S{@Override public void execute(String g, String r){ System.out.println("do the S move here"); }},
        W{@Override public void execute(String g, String r){ System.out.println("do the W move here"); }},
        M{@Override public void execute(String g, String r){ System.out.println("do the M move here"); }};
        public abstract void execute(String g, String r);

    }
    public void nextPosition() {
        Command c1;
        for(int i=0;i<commLength;i++) {
            if (command.charAt(i)=='N'||command.charAt(i)=='E'|| command.charAt(i)=='S'|| command.charAt(i)=='W'||command.charAt(i)=='M')

                c1= Command.M;// Here instead of M, I am trying to give dynamic commands but it is not taking it
            System.out.println("Current position is"+c1);
        }

    //return c1;
    }
}
```

Could someone please suggest me how to call the Enum methods using commands given as input.

Comment: You should make a map of functional interfaces. http://www.baeldung.com/java-8-functional-interfaces

Comment: Better use an `enum` with an `execute()` method in each entry

Comment: Perhaps you are over complicating this. Why not just have a switch statement or if else block for your 4 possible commands.

Comment: Uses of condition branching like if/else or switch is prohibited. That is why have to use some other way to solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

First, it appears the assignment parameters are missing an "initial facing" property or a constraint that the first command will never be M.  (because if you don't have an initial facing, how do you know in which direction to "move forward" if the first command is M?)

However, ignoring that issue, you can use recursion for this solution.  Given the grid size, the starting position, and the list of moves...

```
public GridPosition findFinalPosition(Grid theGrid, GridPosition startPosition, List<MoveDirections> theMoves) {

    if (theMoves.length() == 0) {
       return startPosition;
    }
    GridPosition nextPosition = theGrid.findNextPosition(startPosition, theMoves.getAt(0));

    List<MoveDirections> remainingMoves = new ArrayList<MoveDirections>()
    for (int i = 1; i < theMoves.length(); i++) {
         remainingMoves.add(theMoves.getAt(i));
    }

    return findFinalPosition(theGrid, nextPosition, remainingMoves);
```

With a recursive method like this, you just need to implement "findNextPosition" without using if/else or switch...  (and control for moves that go off the grid, etc.)

Since this seems like an obvious class assignment, I'm not going to show you how I would implement "findNextPosition" without using if/else or switch...  But, hint hint, my solution would implement an enum similar to @Mark Jeronimus's answer.

Answer (score -1):

Using a `Map` for a command sequence does not make any sense, because a map (notwithstanding subclasses) doesn't preserve order of it's elements. It does make sense for mapping commands to functions, but there's an easier way.

This answers the question: "how to call a function through [a] value".

Here's a template for an enum that can execute a method:

```
static enum Command {
    N{@Override public void execute(Grid g, Robot r){ System.out.println("do the N move here"); }},
    E{@Override public void execute(Grid g, Robot r){ System.out.println("do the E move here"); }},
    S{@Override public void execute(Grid g, Robot r){ System.out.println("do the S move here"); }},
    W{@Override public void execute(Grid g, Robot r){ System.out.println("do the W move here"); }},
    M{@Override public void execute(Grid g, Robot r){ System.out.println("do the M move here"); }};
    public abstract void execute(Grid g, Robot r);
}
```

With this enum, you can store a sequence in a list, or pass enums around.

```
    Command c1 = Command.M; // hardcoded Move
    Command c2 = getNextMove(); // from a method: public Command getNextMove(){...}
    Command c3 = list.get(3); // from a collection: List<Command>
```

With any of these instances, you can call the function with a the appropriate instances of your program:

```
    c1.execute(g, r);
```

With `g` and `r` each of the five methods should have enough information to perform a valid robot comand.

Comment: I think we would be getting only one command at a time.And also we need to check that whether the robot can move to that position or not as it may not be end of grid

Comment: I am quiet new using enum, could you please help me how to dynamically give command names instead of hardcoding. I tried this code. Added in the question.

Comment: What do you mean with dynamic names? Do you want to change the name of the command for internationalization, etc, or do you want to dynamically make a list of commands from that static list?